# How can I find the real exception class to handle it?

Tags: java, spring, exception, exceptionhandler

I am developing Rest API. When I am getting exception, I want to handle it with its special exception class. I can understand what the exception class is returned when I run one code block from the outputs. However, I sometimes cannot handle this exception by using the exception class which is seen in the output. I am pasting one example about this problem below. I have used "**MongoWriteException**" for this exception but it did not works. **What is the way to find the exact exception for a run time error?** Also, I added the how to handle the exception.

(Exception Handling Part)
--Service Layer

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentService {
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public List<Student> getAllStudents(){
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Student postAStudent(Student student){
        Student newStudent = new Student();
        newStudent.setFirstname(student.getFirstname());
        newStudent.setLastname(student.getLastname());
        newStudent.setEmail(student.getEmail());
        newStudent.setAddress(student.getAddress());
        newStudent.setGender(student.getGender());
        newStudent.setTotalSpentInBooks(student.getTotalSpentInBooks());
        newStudent.setFavouriteSubjects(student.getFavouriteSubjects());

        try {
            return studentRepository.save(newStudent);
        }catch (MongoWriteException exception){
            throw new EmailAlreadyExistsException("The email was already used.");
        }

    }
}
```

---Controller Layer

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentController {
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getAllStudents(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(studentService.getAllStudents(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Student> postAStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(studentService.postAStudent(student),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleEmailAlreadyExistsException(EmailAlreadyExistsException exception){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getMessage(),HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

---

(Exception Output Part)

```
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Write operation error on server ac-udv2tae-shard-00-01.ur47g8l.mongodb.net:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: productsdb.student index: email dup key: { email: "johndoe@gmail.com" }', details={}}.
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1093) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:478) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:461) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:455) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$insertDocument$17(MongoTemplate.java:1540) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:601) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1534) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:1335) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1261) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:95) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy68.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.mongodb.service.StudentService.postAStudent(StudentService.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.mongodb.controller.StudentController.postAStudent(StudentController.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:259) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:192) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Can you show how you're catching the exceptions now?

Comment: try {
            return studentRepository.save(newStudent);
        }catch (MongoWriteException exception){
            throw new EmailAlreadyExistsException("The email was already used.");
        }

Comment: I've added it to your question, but you should add more information. Can you please add as well the class and the rest of the method where this invocation is made?

Comment: I added controller and service layer sir. I am using model-repository-service-controller layered architecture.

Comment: Spring will convert the exception to a `DataAccessException`, which is a `RuntimeException`. Trying to catch the wrapped exception will not work.

Comment: Thanks so much, sir. I can understand finally what the reason is. Have a good day.